# Exception in thread, java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, graphics, nullpointerexception, jpanel

I have been searching for an answer to this for two days now, but that didn't seem to solve much. Mostly because i don't really understand what is causing my error in the first place, nor would i know how to go about fixing the problem.

I've been trying to make an "animation" of sorts, where one of the layers in it spawn circles on the right side of the screen and send them to the left over time. Problem is every time it is meant to spawn a circle, it doesn't appear and i get an error.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Ball.draw(Ball.java:39)
at Ball.run(Ball.java:23)
```

Here is the class that is causing the errors:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Ball extends Thread{
    JPanel drawingPanel;
    private int x=400,y=200;
    private int dx=-2,dy=0;
    private static final int XSIZE=10,YSIZE=10;
    Random rdm = new Random();
    int y_rdm = rdm.nextInt(440)+30;

    public Ball(JPanel jp){
        drawingPanel=jp;
        dx-=1;

    }
    public void run(){
        draw();
        for (int i=0;i<1000;i++){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){} 
            move();
        }
    }
    private void move(){
        erase();
        changePos();
        draw();
    }
    private void draw(){
        Graphics g = drawingPanel.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillOval(x,y_rdm,XSIZE,YSIZE);
        g.dispose();
    }
    private void erase(){
        Graphics g=drawingPanel.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(drawingPanel.getBackground());
        g.fillOval(x,y_rdm,XSIZE,YSIZE);
        g.dispose();
    }

    private void changePos(){
        x+=dx;y_rdm+=dy;
    }



}
```

---

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class BallPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    JPanel drawingPanel = new JPanel();
    public BallPanel(){

      int delay = 300;
      ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
              Ball b= new Ball(drawingPanel);
                b.start();
          }
      };

      new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();

    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }

}
```

---

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;


public class Window extends JFrame{

      private JLayeredPane layerpane;
      private JPanel up, down;

    public Window(){
          layerpane = new JLayeredPane();

          down = new JPanel();
          down.setBounds(0, 0, 450, 450);
          down.setBackground(new Color(0, 51, 102));
          layerpane.add(down, new Integer(1));

          BallPanel bp = new BallPanel();
          layerpane.add(bp, new Integer(2));
          bp.setBounds(0, 0, 450, 450);
          bp.setOpaque(!bp.isOpaque());

          Animation2 ani2 = new Ani2();
          ani2.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 450);
          layerpane.add(ani2, new Integer(3));

          ani2.setOpaque(!ani2.isOpaque());

         getContentPane().add(layerpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

        public static void main(String args[]){

        JFrame f = new Window();

        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(450,450);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        try{
            URL url = new URL("file:///C://song.mp3");
            InputStream in = url.openStream();
            Player pl = new Player(in);
            pl.play();
            }        

            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 


        }

    }
```

Please tell me if i need to include my other classes, they just seem slightly irrelevant.

Comment: There are no stupid questions.

Comment: What is at line Ball.java:39 in your code?

Comment: The error is that `drawingPanel.getGraphics()` returns null. Read about this [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/407987/java/java/getGraphics-returns-null) and in [StackOverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275259/when-will-getgraphics-return-a-valid-graphics-instance)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That seems like an answer.

Comment: @Hassan I haven't worked with Swing previously, so just providing a link with a possible answer does not fit with my style of answering questions here. I preffer to post an answer from something that I know instead of just posting [dead] links that maybe doesn't provide the exact answer OP's looking for :).

Comment: Maurício Linhares, Ball.java.39 is g.setColor(Color.WHITE); which is why im generally quite confused about this. I don't understand why it points at the lines it points at in the error. Also i'm reading what Luiggi Mendoza posted and so far i can say i'm confused, but i'll keep reading and hope it helps!

Comment: Where is the code where you create a `Ball` instance and make your GUI visible to the user?

Comment: @HotLicks `drawingPanel` is initialized in the constructor

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that.  But no guarantee that `jp` isn't null.

Comment: And no guarantee that `getGraphics` isn't returning null:  "This method will return null if this component is currently not displayable."

Comment: Hot Licks, that is the line Eclipse is telling me it is, i doubt i can count it differently. Jeffry, added it now.

Comment: Display the value of `g` in the debugger.

Comment: There is already a `Window` class in `java.awt`. You might want to reconsider the name of your `Window` class to avoid confusion.

Comment: Jeffrey, yes its not actually called that, i just had to translate it to english quickly

Comment: @Hassan: pretty sure we can find some... (not saying that one is)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `getGraphics` method of `JComponent` returns the `Graphics` object associated with the `Component`. But if there is no `Graphics` object associated it will return null, which is the case in your code.

A `Component` is associated with a `Graphics` object only when it is added to a container that is associated with one, or if it is a Top-Level Container (`JFrame`, `JDialog`, and `JApplet`).

Your problem here is that your `JPanel` is not contained inside any top-level container, so its associated `Graphics` object is null.

To fix the problem, either make sure you have added the `JPanel` to a top-level container before you call `getGraphics()` on it, or instead extend `JPanel` and override its `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method to do the drawing (second option is preferred since the `paintComponent` method is called automatically whenever the parent container needs to be redrawn (e.g. if it was resized, or blocked and unblocked by some other window, ...)).

(By the way, in your `BallPanel` class which extends `JPanel`, you define a new `JPanel` and pass it to `Ball`'s constructor. You should be passing `this` to the the constructor, since the `drawingPanel` is never added to any container, but the `BallPanel` instance itself is. It really doesn't make sense to define a `JPanel` field inside a class which is itself a `JPanel` and have the field do the job that the class itself is supposed to do.)